# react-select dropdown opens inside modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select, css-modules

I have a custom modal where I have 2 react-select components inside. The modal body is ready to auto scroll in case the content exceeds its size, but the react-select components dropdown open inside the modal with this overflow, which is what i am not looking for. Without overflow, it works fine.

I'm working with CSS Modules.

```
<div className={styles.modalBody}>
    {this.props.children}
</div>

.modalBody {
    padding: padding;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    height: 45vh;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

<Select
    id={this.props.id}
    className={styles[this.props.selectType ? this.props.selectType : 'selectWhite']}
    classNamePrefix="select"
    name={this.props.name}
    value={selectedOption ? selectedOption : this.props.value}
    placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
    onChange={this.onChange}
    options={this.props.options}
    isDisabled={this.props.disabled}
    isSearchable={false}/>
```

How can I fix this? 
Thank you! :)

Comment: Can you explain what you do want to happen? Also, a code sandbox would be helpful here.

Comment: I would like the select menu to show above the modal

Comment: This StackOverFlow [answer fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55830799/how-to-change-zindex-in-react-select-drowpdown) my issue.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You want to look at the `menuPortalTarget` prop. There's a [topic on this in the Advanced documentation](https://react-select.com/advanced#portaling), specifically with a modal example provided. Something like:

```
  <Select
    {...otherProps}
    menuPortalTarget={document.body} />
```

Comment: Perfect solution. I also combined this with the `menuShouldScrollIntoView` prop as well.

Comment: This is a better answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57089251/react-select-can-not-overlay-react-modal

Comment: This worked very well. Just added menuPortalTarget={document.body} styles={{ menuPortal: (base) => ({ ...base, zIndex: 9999 }) }}

Comment: The response from @RohitParte should be in the accepted answer. The zIndex is crucial when there is a modal.

Answer (score 6):

You can use Menu Position as fixed by setting the prop,which in turn makes your dropdown as position fixed as

```
<Select menuPosition="fixed" />
```

Comment: simple elegant solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

A full example of how to display the select menu in a modal (I added comments at important lines and a step-by-step explanation below):

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import { Dialog } from '@mui/material';

const MyModal: React.FC = () => {
    const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    return (
        <Dialog
            // ...
            ref={ref} // stores a ref to the DOM node of the modal component
        >
            <Select
                // ...
                menuPortalTarget={ref.current} // pass the ref to `Select` to portal the select menu to the given DOM node
                styles={{
                    menuPortal: defaultStyles => ({  
                        ...defaultStyles,
                        paddingBottom: '10px', // style the menu when it's portalled into the DOM node given to `menuPortalTarget`
                    }),
                }}
            />
        </Dialog>
    );
};

export default MyModal;
```

**Step-by-step explanation**:

1. I create a `ref` with the `React.useRef` hook.
2. I'm getting a reference of the `Dialog` component (which in this example is a [MUI dialog](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-dialog/) component (but could be any other Modal component) via `ref={ref}`
3. I pass that `ref` to `react-select`'s `Select` component via `menuPortalTarget={ref.current}`.
4. I had to customize the placement of the menu via `paddingBottom: '10px',` because the menu would appear a bit too high in my case. You might have to adjust this differently.

**Further comments**:

- `document.body` didn't do the trick for me. The menu appeared behind the modal for me in this case.
- Unfortunately the [`react-select` portaling docs](https://react-select.com/advanced#portaling) do not contain any example code, so I hope this example is helpful to you.

Comment: document.body didn't work for you because zIndex of your modal was higher than zIndex of menuPortal. It should be enough to set correct zIndex on menuPortal (same method like you set paddingBottom).