# How to change zIndex in react-select drowpdown

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am using the react-select library to create autocomplete drop-down.
I have used 2 drop-down parallel if 2nd has some data & I open first one then the zIndex problem comes. see the image[image]

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us what you have done so far.

Comment: Very good question i just had the same problem today!

Comment: https://thewebdev.info/2021/11/20/how-to-change-zindex-of-the-items-in-a-react-select-drop-down/
check this if it helps

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Add these lines in your all `Select` tag:

```js
<Select 
    // other props
    menuPortalTarget={document.body} 
    styles={{ menuPortal: base => ({ ...base, zIndex: 9999 }) }}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Save my day! It should be the most robust solution.  If the parent container has `overflow: hidden`, just setting `menu` z-index to 9999 cannot prevent the popup cropped by the parent container.

Comment: You made my day, this solution is for the case u have a parent div which set overflow: hidden.   `menuPortalTarget={document.body} 
` did the trick

Comment: this is not working , Vicente's answer is working

Comment: This solved my issue. I was opening it inside a small dialog, but I needed it outside. Thank you!

Comment: For some reason, this removes any font styles applied to custom components. Overriding the z-index of `menu` instead of `menuPortal` does not do this.

Comment: yey!!! i am using react-select-country-list which uses react-select and with this code added to the select component it worked!!! thanks so much

Comment: This breaks when scrolling. The menu does not move with the parent element.

Comment: the doc is super large; thx for the hint

Answer (score 76):

Try this hacky way of setting zIndex, and let me know if it worked :)

```
<Select
  styles={{
    // Fixes the overlapping problem of the component
    menu: provided => ({ ...provided, zIndex: 9999 })
  }}
  value={selectedOption}
  onChange={evt => onSelectChange(evt, index)}
  options={options}
/>
```

Comment: depending of @user11124592's markdown and CSS you're solution is completely valid and not necessary "hacky" :)

Comment: @Vicente thanks for your answer.  If anyone else comes here and has trouble with this approach.  You might be using the portal of react-select which in that case you need to use:

```menuPortal: provided => ({ ...provided, zIndex: 9999 })```

Comment: @Vicente, I have a similar problem, but I cannot display the zIndex.
Do you have any other properties for the dropdown to overlap the other components?

Comment: This is the superior solution. It's simpler and it can be applied to all Select components using a custom styles object. Additionally the other solution breaks when the page is scrolled as the portal is tied to the document body and not the menu element. Also it's not hacky, this is why z-index exists.

Answer (score 59):

After seeing the half dozen related issues, yet not finding a resolution, I have finally found one.

```
<Select
    menuPortalTarget={document.body}
    menuPosition='fixed'
/>
```

Add these two options to your Select component.

It appears to make us of the new [React Portal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) feature.

EDIT: If you do the above, you then run into this problem with the menu anchoring to the page due to `position: fixed`. Removing it may help. https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/4088

Comment: Correction here - the menuPosition={'fixed'} should be menuPosition="fixed", with double quotes.

Comment: Double quotes or single quotes both work. It's a style preference.

Comment: Absolutely! Have a good one!

Comment: This fixed my problem! I have a material-react-table w/ the form dropdown located above the table. Adding these 2 lines made it so the dropdown items are above the table! I used menuPosition="fixed"

Answer (score 12):

For me the solution was kind of the total of all the answers (thanks!);

```
 const customStyles = {
    ///.....
    menuPortal: provided => ({ ...provided, zIndex: 9999 }),
    menu: provided => ({ ...provided, zIndex: 9999 })
    ///.....
  }


 <Select
  //.....
  menuPortalTarget={document.body}
  menuPosition={'fixed'} 
  styles={customStyles}
  //.....
  />
```

Comment: Adding yours "customStyles" only, works for me with "zIndex: 1000". But be careful with "Tooltips" or "Popovers" and add "zIndex" accordingly

Comment: You can remove menuPosition={'fixed'} attribute. It prevents scrolling if menu list overflows page.

Answer (score 5):

Just simply add the below two lines of code.

```js
 const customStyles = {
    ///.....
    menuPortal: provided => ({ ...provided, zIndex: 5 }),
   
    ///.....
  }

 <Select
  //.....
  menuPosition={'fixed'} 
  styles={customStyles}
  //.....
  />
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way is We can config the `classNamePrefix` and control it through the outer class.

```
import Select from "react-select";

<Select
   classNamePrefix={"my-custom-react-select"}
/>
```

```
.my-custom-react-select__menu {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Bonus, We can re-style everything

```
.my-custom-react-select__control {
  border-width: 1px !important;
  border-color: #cbd5e0 !important;
  padding-top: 0.16rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.16rem;
}

.my-custom-react-select__control--is-focused {
  border-color: #746df7 !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

.my-custom-react-select__indicator-separator {
   display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Only combination of those answers made the working solution for me on `Next.js`. `menuPortalTarget={document.body}` broke the application with the error `ReferenceError: document is not defined`, which makes sense on `SSG`/`SSR` :)

`menuPosition={"fixed"}` as suggested by @I Stand With Israel **with combination of answer** from @hemant rao: `menuPortal: (base) => ({ ...base, zIndex: 4 }),`.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution when using "react-select" (version 4.3.1)

```
import ReactSelect from 'react-select';
...
...
<ReactSelect
  className="custom_zindex"
  ...
  ...
/>
```

In the css file:

```
.custom_zindex {
   z-index: 100;  /* or 999 */
}
```

"className" is one of the props in react-select (https://react-select.com/props).

Answer (score 1):

TLDR:

In your (S)CSS, add this:

```
div[class*="-MenuPortal"] {
    z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

It is so sad to see react developers raping CSS by putting styling into javascript.
For any and all developers that think this is in any way a good idea - PLEASE STOP!
CSS is there to do this stuff, not javascript. JS doesn't know where it's going to be in the DOM, so its support for the 'C' in CSS is at best a lucky guess.

Others have mentioned the term 'hacky' - there are few things hackier than auto-gen'ing css class names with JS.

Some of the answers above will work...sometimes...but they all rely on JS playing ball, which JS is simply not in a position to do.

So...here is a hacky solution for react-select dropdowns (this technique will work with any horrid auto-gen-css JS library) to work all the time - whether deep in the DOM or in a Modal/top-level and so on.

In your (S)CSS, add this:

```
div[class*="-MenuPortal"] {
    z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

This will set the z-index for any div that has a class that contains -MenuPortal.
Since you won't know the class name due to the infinite wisdom of react-select styling in JS, at least until they decide to change the autogen naming of classes (yuk!) to not include -MenuPortal this will work.

There is of course a possibility there is another div in your DOM that has this string - let's just hope it's another dropdown menu!

Apologies retrospectively for my soapbox rant on CSS-in-JS. With luck, one day there will be World Peace and JS will be a distant memory. In the meantime, keeping CSS well away from javascript and vide-versa is always a prudent move!

Happiness and smiles to you all! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The code below worked for me. zIndex does not need to be 9999 (as suggested in other answers); just make sure the menu dropdown has a higher zIndex value than the other HTML elements.

```js
<Select
  styles={{
    // Fixes the overlapping problem of the component
    menu: (base) => ({ ...base, zIndex: 2 })
  }}
  value={selectedOption}
  onChange={(evt) => onSelectChange(evt, index)}
  options={options}
/>
```

Answer (score -6):

Change the zIndex of the parent component of this select

```
<div style={{zIndex:1000}}>
  <React-Select-Component/>
</div>
```