# How to fix styling on react-select dropdown when using menuPortalTarget

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

When I use `menuPortalTarget` it breaks the styling on my dropdown. Here is a [**codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandboxer-example-forked-lhuud?file=/example.js:2460-2476) showing the problem. In the codesandbox I have a button to toggle `menuPortalTarget`. When `menuPortalTarget` is active and you open the dropdown you can see the messed up styling vs when its not active.

I tried playing around with the parent styling and the `menuPortal` styling but I couldn't get it working.

This example is based off [this](https://react-select.com/advanced#experimental) from the react-select docs.

Comment: Facing similar issue too. This worked for me [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63898744/20073649).

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
const selectStyles = {
  control: (provided) => ({ ...provided, minWidth: 240, margin: 8 }),
  menu: () => ({ boxShadow: "inset 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)" }),
  menuPortal: () => ({ zIndex: "1000", width: "240px", position: "absolute", top: "214px", backgroundColor: "white", left: "17px", boxShadow: "inset 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)" })
};
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me:

```html
<Select menuPosition="fixed" />
```

Comment: 1. Install
     packagenpm i --save react-select
2. Import in the respective file
     import Select from 'react-select'
3. Include below code snippet

     const options = [
        { value: 'apple', label: 'Apple' },
        { value: 'orange', label: 'Orange' },
        { value: 'banana', label: 'Banana' }
      ]

const MyComponent = () => (
  <Select options={options} />
)