# React select can not overlay react modal

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a react modal and inside it I have `react-select`. How can I make select overlay the modal because some of my options in the botttom of modal did not appear ?
[image: RM]

I tried `z-index` but it did not work.

```
<MainSelect
        className="select"
        id={name}
        isMulti
        isRtl={!locale.ltr}
        components={{ Option: OptionComponent }}
        styles={this.customStyles}
        theme={this.customTheme}
        options={options}
        value={value}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        onBlur={formik.onBlur}
        onMenuOpen={() => {
          if (setScroll) setScroll();
          this.props.formik.setStatus("onMenuOpen");
        }}
      />
```

Answer (score 9):

As stated in this StackOverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54906229/8808193), the `menuPortalTarget` allows you to select the dom node over which the menu is overlayed.

```
<Select
 menuPortalTarget={document.body}
 styles={{
     menuPortal: base => ({ ...base, zIndex: 9999 })
 }}
/>
```

Comment: You should add some more information explaining why the code that you posted could help the original poster

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is the default style of React Modal i.e `overflow:hidden`. And `React-modal` allows you to easily override default styles. Just add `overflow: visible` to the modal's CSS.

Comment: but ihave already scroll on the modal but the select at the modal bottom go inside and last option did not appear

Comment: for me the solution was overflow:visible on .modal-body

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to set a className property on the Bootstrap modal, so you can easily select it in the DOM. Then in the react-select component, use the menuPortalTarget prop to specify that the dropdown menu should be attached to the modal. Use something similar to this:

```js
<Select
  ...
  menuPortalTarget={document.querySelector('.my-modal')}
  styles={{
    menuPortal: base => ({ ...base, zIndex: 9999 }),
  }}
/>
```